# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE -specified settings file not loaded?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-settings, django-1.2

I'm [migrating a Google App Engine application from Django 0.96 to 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844301/migrating-a-google-app-engine-application-from-django-0-96-to-django-1-2). In the process, I noted that the settings file I specified in my main handler was not loaded anymore (instead of the 3 specified languages, Django loaded the full list of default languages from it's `django/conf/global_settings.py` file).

In 0.96 I specified the file like this:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'conf.settings'
```

From what I read in the documentation this is not supposed to be changed. However, when specifying version 1.2 like this:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
```

`conf.settings` is not imported anymore. Digging a bit in the GAE's SDK, I noted that the 0.96 and 1.2 versions of the `google_appengine/lib/django_<VERS>/django/conf/__init__.py` file work differently.

In 0.96, `LazySettings._import_settings` gets called from `LazySettings.__getattr__`, which results in the file specified in `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` to be imported.

In 1.2, `LazySettings._setup` does not seem to be called anywhere.

If I add a manual call to `settings._setup()` in my main handler, the custom settings file gets imported properly. Like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings._target = None # Force Django to reload settings
settings._setup()
```

However, it feels weird/wrong to have to call that private function manually... Why is my custom settings file not imported anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good explanation of what's going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994913/app-engine-default-django-version-change/5032415#5032415):

> Django settings are loaded from the
>   specified settings.py lazily, the
>   first time they are accessed. The
>   problem is that importing
>   webapp.template calls
>   django.conf.settings.configure() to
>   attempt to set up some settings.
>   Therefore if webapp.template is
>   imported before any settings are
>   accessed, then settings.py is never
>   loaded (as the settings accessor finds
>   that settings already exist, and
>   doesn't attempt to load any more).
>
> The solution to this is to force an
>   access to the settings, to load the
>   settings.py, before webapp.template is
>   imported. Then when webapp.template is
>   later imported, its call to
>   django.conf.settings.configure() is
>   ignored.

Sounds like a bug to me. You could submit it to [the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Comment: Indeed, moving the settings import before importing webapp solved this. I'll open an issue to report this. Thanks.